# jQuery .submit not passing parameters with method POST

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I have a form that goes something like this:

```
<form id="lista-documentos" method="post">
    <input type=... />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="req" />
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="documentos" />
</form>
```

And it asks for user confirmation via jQuery UI. Also, the hidden parameters get dynamic values, depending on user actions:

```
//jQuery modal confirmation
...
$('input[name=documentos]').val(values);
$('input[name=req]').val(6);
$( this ).dialog( "close" );
$('#lista-documentos').submit();
...
```

Everything works fine except when I use the POST method on the form declaration. Using GET passes the parameters to the servlet but not in POST.

Firebug confirms that when using POST, the parameters do not get appended to the request.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: Where is your `action` within the form?

Comment: @Dutchie432 I knew I was missing something very basic... Guess I'll stop coding for the day! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may add a name for your form.

```
{"error": "Shell form does not validate{'html_initial_name': u'initial-js_lib', 'form': <mooshell.forms.ShellForm object at 0xab9a42c>, 'html_name': 'js_lib', 'label': u'Js lib', 'field': <django.forms.models.ModelChoiceField object at 0xacabb4c>, 'help_text': '', 'name': 'js_lib'}"}
```